# Secondary submit function for form input button

Tags: 6, forms

I want to have buttons for remove selected field from form.

```
    $form['questions']['buttons'][$counter] = array(
        '#type' => 'button', 
        '#name' =>'button_'.$counter, 
        '#value' => t('Remove'),
        '#submit' => array('my_mod_remove_submit'),
    );
```

Submit function:

```
function my_mod_remove_submit($form, &$form_state) {
    drupal_set_message('<pre>'.print_r($form_state, 1).'</pre>');
}
```

But it seems that this function is never invoke.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with your code is the default value for the form field attributes. In the case of the "button" form field, these are the default values:

- `#name` => 'op'
- `#button_type` => 'submit'
- `#executes_submit_callback` => FALSE
- `#ahah['event']` => 'mousedown'

Those are also the default values for Drupal 7.

If you want to use a submission callback for a button, then you need to change the form field definition to the following one:

```
$form['questions']['buttons'][$counter] = array(
  '#type' => 'button', 
  '#name' =>'button_' . $counter, 
  '#value' => t('Remove'),
  '#executes_submit_callback' => TRUE,
  '#submit' => array('my_mod_remove_submit'),
);
```

As alternative, instead of using a "button" form field, you should use a "submit" form field.

Answer (score 1):

Change the input type from "button" to "submit"

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to manage multiple submit buttons associated with their data to perform operations on it.

The better approach is to use check boxes with a single submit button.

e.g.

```
function my_form(){
  $data_ids = array();

  foreach($data_set as $data){
    $data_ids[$data] = '';
    $form['data']['data_preview'][$data['id']] = array('#value' => $data['value']);
  }

  $form['selection'] = array(
    '#type' => 'checkboxes'
    '#options' => $data_ids;
  );

  $form['process'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => 'do',
  );

  $form['#theme'] = 'my_form';
}
```

Theme handler (do not forget to implement `my_form` entry in `hook_theme`)

```
function theme_my_form($form = array()){
  $rows = array();
  foreach(element_children($form['selection']) as $id) {
    $fields = array();
    $fields[] = drupal_render($form['selection'][$id]);
    $fields[] = drupal_render($form['data']['data_preview'][$id]);
    $rows[] = $fields;
  }

  $output = theme('table', array('Select', 'Data'), $rows);
  $output .= drupal_render($form);// Render rest of form
  return $output;
}
```

Now form submit handler

```
function my_form_submit(&$form, $form_state){
  $clicked_button = $form_state['clicked_button']['#value'];
  $values = $form_state['values'];

  if ($clicked_button == $values['process']){
       //Here check $value['selection'] array and process accordingly
  }
}
```